# forcing glutCreateWindow to create the window on a specific monitor in a dual screen setup

Tags: glut, multiple-monitors

I was wondering if there's a way to force the window created using glutCreateWindow (along with the associated command prompt for my application ) to open on a specific monitor in my dual monitor setup. I use one monitor for coding and would like to use the other for actually running my application everytime I fire it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using only glut. Your solution is going to be specific to the operating system that your program runs on.

Getting this to work is going to be far more effort than it is worth considering you want to do this just to speed up your workflow a bit.